# Table with only one row bigger than it should be

Tags: html, css

I'm creating an html page, im creating a table with the following code:

```
<table style="border-spacing: 85px; position: relative; bottom: 0px" align="center" >
        <tr>
            <td>one</td>
            <td>Two</td>
            <td>Three</td>
        </tr>
 </table>
```

As you can see there is only one TR, but when i open the code on any browser the tables height is 192px,the tbody's height is 192px but the TR's height is just 22px.
Why is the browser creating that big table if i only need the TR's height which is 22px?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because of the "border-spacing: 85px" that you've specified in the table style.  85 px above the row + 85 px below the row + 22px for the row itself = 192px.

If you just want the height of the row, remove that style spec:

```
<table style="position: relative; bottom: 0px" align="center" >
        <tr>
            <td>one</td>
            <td>Two</td>
            <td>Three</td>
        </tr>
</table>
```

**EDIT: (addressing asker question in comments)**

In order to separately specify vertical and horizontal spacing, make sure to use 2 arguments to "border-spacing".  The first argument specifies horizontal spacing and the second specifies vertical.  Example:

```
<table style="border-spacing: 85px 3px; position: relative; bottom: 0px" align="center" >
        <tr>
            <td>one</td>
            <td>Two</td>
            <td>Three</td>
        </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: That's right thank you, but how can i give a space between each column (TD)? Thats why i used the border-spacing: 85px

Comment: Ah, you need to specify two things in border spacing.  If you just specify one, it goes for both horizontal and vertical spacing.  If you do two, it will apply the first one to horizontal spacing and the second one to vertical spacing.  I'll update the example in my answer to show it.

Comment: You can use margin or padding which seems more appropriate for what you're trying to do. Just try seting a margin for all columns using a css stylesheet.

Comment: If this helped, please accept it as the answer to your question (woo, reputation!).